# Java: Are there any foss image SPI implementations other than the bundled ones?

Tags: java, image-processing

Doing a search for implementations of the various image reader and writer interfaces etc all i could find where refernces about the bundled implementations provided by Sun. Are there actually any foss libraries out there w/ their own implementations ?